# Install a package and its associated or required shared libraries (.so) without sudo access

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user, shared-library

I needed to install `ffmpeg` on my company's server without `sudo` access. Here is how I did it:

1. Add `$HOME/bin` and `$HOME/usr/bin` to my `PATH`, and `$HOME/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. Download `ffmpeg` to my `HOME` with the command `apt-get download`, and install it (binary file went into `$HOME/usr/bin`) with `dpkg -x [ffmpeg .deb file] .`
3. When I run `ffmpeg`, I encountered missing shared libraries like `libSDL2-2.0.so.0`, `libass.so.9`,... So I decided to run `ffmpeg` again and again to find the missing shared libraries (.so files) and install it with 2 steps in step 2: `apt-get download` and `dpkg -x`.

I did it 57 times until I got all the `.so` files and ran the `ffmpeg` successfully. However, I had to do it since I can't find a way to get all the right necessary `.so` files for a package without `sudo` privileges.  Can anyone help me with a (much) better process for this? I heard about JuNest but I want a traditional approach first if possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Easiest solution is to present a business case to the IT group on why you need to stream audio and video on a company server. After the request is reviewed and approved the application and all libraries can be properly installed.

Comment: @doneal24 Thanks for your suggestion, my company's IT group often handles requests in 1-3 business days so it's a lot of time for an urgent task. But still worth a try next time.

Comment: How much time did you spend running 57 instances of tracking down shared libraries and installing them? If it is an time-sensitive task can the request be marked as urgent and expedited? How much time will you dedicate to keeping the package and libraries up to date? Is the company willing to pay you to do a task that belongs to the IT staff?

Comment: I see your point, actually, it's part of my bad experience with the IT group that made me do it my way instead. I just track shared libraries by running `ffmpeg` and get the error which is the library I need to install next. Took about 45-60 seconds per library. Only a few need more searching. I did all those thing in 1 hour.

Comment: Just as a warning, if my company found a person streaming video through a company server (or desktop) using company resources (cpu, disk, network bandwidth) and bypassing company policies, that employee would be reprimanded in some fashion and the installation deleted. Future offences could result in termination.

Comment: Yes. One should always take care on what one are doing. That said I've worked at places where we talk weeks for requests to get resolved; often with IT dept off site and/or outsourced. Sometimes one need a tool for an ad-hock solution to get work done. Install, work, wipe, done. It does not hurt to send a "urgent" message first of course, and would likely be a good thing to have if they complain ;)

Answer (score 1):

A hackish way: You could do a `simulate` install i.e.

```bash
apt -s install ffmpeg
```

Look for:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libavdevice57 libsdl2-2.0-0
```

Then something like:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir alt/mysoft/ffmpeg
$ cd alt/mysoft/ffmpeg

$ apt-get download ffmpeg libavdevice57 libsdl2-2.0-0

$ for f in *; do dpkg -x "$f" ../..; done

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/alt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/alt/usr/bin"

$ ffmpeg -version
```

You'd like to add the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` additions to some startup file as not to re-download exiting dependencies.

Comment: Oh, the output is like magic, worth a try! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng Maybe not strictly applicable on this forum but several SE sites explicitly forbid questions on how to bypass institutional policies.

Comment: @ibuprofen Don't worry, my case didn't violate the policy, I asked my manager just in case.